# How do I center text in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, center, text-align

Does anyone know why my top row is not center? I have attached the picture of my table for reference. The Product Sales headings are not center. In my html code you only need to pay attention to header-cell div class as that is where I wrote code for the top row. I tried all the centering techniques I know in the CSS file but none seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

```css
.single-cell {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-cell {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <div class="header-cell">
      <tr>
        <b>Month</b>
      </tr>
    </div>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="header-cell">
        <tr>
          <b>{{ p.salesLabel }}</b>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <th *ngFor="let p of products">
      <div class="single-cell">
        <tr>
          <input style="border: none" type="text" name="cogs-label" />
        </tr>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: text-align: center maybe

Comment: Your html is broken in several relevant ways. `div` [isn't valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#technical_summary) as a child of `tr`, for example.

Comment: @rayhatfield Okay,  I fixed that but nothing changed

Comment: your code doesn't match your picture. please lookup how to ask a question on stackoverflow

Comment: Could you update the code in your question so it reflects the changes you have made to make it have a correct HTML structure (following @rayhatfield comment);

Comment: your html code is completely messed up. Kindly first correct it, only then , someone can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table structure is very wrong structured.
F.ex. a tr is not a child of a div, but either thead, tbody, tfoot or the table it self.
Don't mix td and th. th is for thead and td is for tbody and tfoot.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Product 1 Sales</th>
        <th>Product 2 Sales</th>
        <th>Product 3 Sales</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[How to create a table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)